# Ajax post not sending data to PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

So I am working on a project in which I have to pass some form data to a database without reloading the page using Ajax. But the $_POST variable in the PHP file is always empty. I do know that I am actually getting the data from the form since I can print and it looks okay in the javascript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

  $('form').on('submit', function (event) {
    // prevent page from refreshing
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'post.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {name: 'tony'},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (response) {
        $('#message').html(response);
      }
    });

    //return false;
  });
});
```

And this is the php code:

```
<?php 
  //var_dump($_POST);
  if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo $name;
  } else {
    echo "error";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Remove `dataType: 'json'`... You tell Ajax that you are expecting a json as response... And it's obvioulys not a json that is sent... But a string.

Comment: Problems with the response type aside, how are you verifying that _"the $_POST variable in the PHP file is always empty"_?

Comment: I do it by navigating to the post.php page and it prints the empty array and "error".
Do you thinks this is not the right way to check it ??

Comment: That was the problem after all, I was verifiyng that the $_POST variable was empty the wrong way. It was working fine after all the whole time. Thank you very much for your help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead, you won't need to manually define the parameters to be sent because it will be automatically set by FormData():

```
$('#form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "post.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out I am just stupid.. It was actually working properly after all but I was checking if it works the wrong way. I was actually navigating to the php file by entering the url expecting to see my data printed on the php page. Finally, I checked the response of the POST request and it was working just fine.Thank you for your answers and I apologize for wasting your time.

Answer (score -2):

**try this,**

```
  $('form').on('submit', function (event) {
   // prevent page from refreshing
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
       url: 'post.php',
       method: 'POST',
       data: {name: 'tony'},
       success: function (response) {
         $('#message').html(response);
       }
    });
  });
```